# Выгрузка данных в Excel с помощью perl

Tags: apache, excel, perl

Данные выгружаются из БД Oracle скриптом Perl.
Эти данные отображаются пользователю на странице, а также выгружаются в excel файл, ссылка на скачивание также есть на этой страничке.
Проблема с выгрузкой данных: например 2 поля, счёт клиента и его номер мобильного телефона. На самой страничке они отображаются корректно: 00933123456789 и 375291234567. Но в excel у счетов пропадают первые два нуля и счета с телефоном отображаются в виде: 7,53E+11.
Например, если в excel поменять формат ячеек для телефонов на числовой, то телефоны нормально отображаются, но у счетов пропадают первые два нуля в любом случае.
Как исправить ситуацию?
На страничку данные выводятся так:
$sth -> bind_columns( undef, \$n1, \$n2, \$n3, \$n4, \$n5, \$n6, \$n7, \$n8, \$n9, \$n10 );
while($sth->fetch()) {print qq|\n\t\t$n1.....$n10|;}
А в EXCEL файл так:
$worksheet->write($row,$col0, $n1);
и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Перед нулями попробуйте добавить одиночную кавычку `'`, чтобы Эксель не умничал с форматами.

Comment: $worksheet->write($row,$col0, $n1); - пробовал $n1 заключать в одиночные и двойные ковычки.

Comment: Как при создании документа перлом указать ему, что первый столбец документа имеет формат текст?

Comment: Sevastopol', из Internet Explorer-а мне не удалось написать свой "ответ" как комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел в документации metacpan:
$worksheet->write($row,$col0, $n1);
заменил на 
$worksheet->write_string($row,$col0, $n1);. И теперь в переменной n1 все передается как надо в excel.